# How can I resolve this error in Delphi 2010: "[DCC Error] E2223 $DENYPACKAGEUNIT 'OleAuto' cannot be put into a package"?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am converting a component package from Delphi 2007 to Delphi 2010.

When I do a full build, it compiles and begins to link.  During linking, I get two messages:

```
[DCC Warning] MyPackage.dpk(235): W1033 Unit 'OleAuto' implicitly imported into package 'MyPackage'
[DCC Error] E2223 $DENYPACKAGEUNIT 'OleAuto' cannot be put into a package
```

What determines the units in $DENYPACKAGEUNIT?  How should I resolve this error?

Answer (score 7):

I found this inside the OleAuto.pas unit, which pretty much answers my question.

```
unit OleAuto deprecated;

{$DENYPACKAGEUNIT}

{ OleAuto cannot be used in a package DLL.  To implement
  an OLE automation server in a package, use the new
  OLE automation support in comobj and comserv.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that someone had placed a call to MtsObj file, thats what seemed be to causing my issue.